# Outlook Custom Form Script Won't Run

Tags: vba, outlook

Since the most recent security update for Outlook my code won't run. Using Outlook 2010. Have a contact form with custom code behind. I click a custom button to open a post item in the History folder. The post item has custom code behind it to write information to a text file. Very important for this to run. Since a few days ago the code on the post item doesn't run anymore. But if I save the post item, close it and reopen it the code runs fine. What is happening and how do I fix it?

```
'this is the code on the contact form
Sub CallFromButton

    'get the folder
    Dim HistFolder
    Set HistFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders("History")

    'add a post item
    Dim blgItem 'PostItem
    Set blgItem = HistFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Post.ClientHistory2")

    'set some information
    blgItem.BillingInformation = "60000"
    blgItem.UserProperties("ClientName") = item.FullName
    blgItem.UserProperties("blgDate") = Now
    blgItem.Display

    '... more code

End Sub 

'this is the code behind the post item
Sub Item_Open()
    Dim LogPage
    Set LogPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("Log Item")
    LogPage.Controls("ResumeBtn").Visible = False
    LogPage.Controls("BoxDesc").SetFocus
    Item.UserProperties("blgFileName") = "C:\Temp\12345.txt"

    '... more code

End Sub

Function Item_Write()

    '... more code

End Function
```

Comment: Custom Forms are horribly broken in recent versions of Outlook. Getting a form to work can involve anything from deleting your local cache to re-creating the form entirely from scratch to praying, with no guarantee that a published form that works today will still work tomorrow, or survive the next change you make. It's a complete mess.

Comment: In other words, if you get a response that works reliably, ping me, I'd love to know as well.

Comment: @Tomalak Well if I can't get it to work I might need to go to a MS competitor. Meaning I'll have a lot more work to do.

Comment: Outlook forms is pretty much dead as a feature, if you ask me. They've done the minimum amount of work to integrate it into current versions of Outlook (or it works by pure chance because it's still in the code-base), but I don't think it has received any developer time at MS since Outlook 2000.

Comment: Custom forms must now be enabled in the registry https://support.office.com/en-us/article/custom-form-script-is-now-disabled-by-default-bd8ea308-733f-4728-bfcc-d7cce0120e94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent Windows update caused this. You can either uninstall it, or wait for a fix from Microsoft: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e6147cb8-fe1c-4d90-a65a-33b8a7b22a6d/june-security-patch-and-issue-with-custom-forms?forum=outlook

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-known-issues-in-the-June-2017-security-updates-3f6dbffd-8505-492d-b19f-b3b89369ed9b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1